# similar triangles problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

> Find x.

Since triangle ABC is similar to ADE then I got:
\begin{align*}
\frac{AB}{AE} &= \frac{AC}{DE} = \frac{BC}{AD} \\
\frac94 &= \frac{4+x}{DE} = \frac{BC}{3} \\
\end{align*}

I found BC = 6.75 but I cannot find DE or x.

Comment: I think you are supposed to interpret it as a right triangle so you can use the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: $|DE|^2=|AE|^2-|AD|^2=4^2-3^2$

Comment: If $⊿ABC \sim  ⊿ADE$, then you should have $\dfrac {AC}{AE}$ but you have … instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{3}{4}=\frac{4+x}{9}=\cos(A)$  Ya gotta work with what you have, and that is not the lengths of DE or BC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming angles ACB and and ADE are the same.

Hint:
What can you say about angles AED and ABC? Consider the ratio of the sides opposite to these angles to their hypotenuse.

EDIT: Originally I assumed that angles ACB and ADE were right angles, but you don't need to make this assumption.

Comment: absolutely, we do not know that they are right angles nor can we assume it.

Comment: if we can't assume the angles are right... why can we assume that the points ADB or AEC are collinear? From what I can tell, x could be infinity or it could be 0, the diagram doesn't give enough information.